# Are there any in-memory (persistent) solutions faster than Aerospike for a single-node?

Tags: aerospike, key-value-store, nosql

I am working on a cloud application that requires low latency and very high read/writes per second. I will only have around 1 million records stored persistently but this may fluctuate largely as the application runs.

After YCSB benchmarking Aerospike and Redis, I found that Aerospike beats Redis and MongoDB both in terms of performance on a single-node for 60/40 read write.

Some points to note:

- Fetching all my data using a single 32-bit integer key (no advanced queries)
- Running on a single machine with 8 GB RAM and an SSD (small number of records)
- Multiple clients need access to the database at once (via LAN)

I'm also assuming that key-value stores will outperform document stores and are the best fit considering I do not need advanced queries.

**Before committing myself to Aerospike, are there any other solutions which may be more fit for my scenario considering that I am only running a single node with a small-ish amount of records?**

Comment: Is SharedHashFile [1] something you'd consider?
[1] https://github.com/simonhf/sharedhashfile

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm aware of. I think Aerospike is the fastest.
However, for some use cases you can consider Tarantool.
Here's one of the benchmarks: https://medium.com/@rvncerr/tarantool-vs-competitors-racing-in-microsoft-azure-ebde9c5d619